# What PHP / MySQL drivers or Database Abstraction Layers Support Prepared Statements?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement, database-abstraction

I am working on a project that is built on an extended version of the default PDO and PDOStatement classes and as such it uses PDO style named parameters instead of the "?" placeholder for variables.

However, the client is now requesting that we look into using a different driver because their version OS X Web Server apparently doesn't have the ability to install this driver easily. So is anyone aware of any other database abstraction libraries or database access drivers that I could easily extend with our current set of functionality that takes named parameters like PDO does?

Comment: hmm that seems odd, are they using php4 or something? i thought php5 (with pdo compiled in) came default in os x server these days.

Comment: PDO is compiled in by default on PHP 5.1 and newer.

Comment: I found it odd too. I'm simply going off what the guys from Apple are telling our client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO and ADODB both support prepared statements, but the API is not great. Most frameworks provide an abstraction to one of those.

I'm using Zend_Db from the Zend Framework and I highly recommend it. It has a select class for composing queries (which turn into prepared statements when queried against the database adapter), a table class for handling CRUD operations - which I use as a base for most of my models and much more.

Check it out [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html).

Comment: I've actually built a custom abstraction layer that we're using but a lot of our custom framework mimics the approach taken by Zend so I had considered looking at the way Zend Framework mocked named parameters for the MySQL driver.

Answer (score 0):

I've used PEAR::MDB2 as well as PDO. MDB2's documentation is a little shaky, but once you get it all working its a dream to work with.

http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2

Answer (score 0):

I think [Creole](http://creole.phpdb.org) offers the requested features...but I didn't try it.

Answer (score 0):

[ADODB](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/) supports [prepared statements](http://phplens.com/adodb/reference.functions.prepare.html).